# how to covert image view into bitmap in android studio?

Tags: android, image, bitmap

Can anyone tell me how to convert imageview to bitmap? In my app, i'm accessing the gallery and getting a bitmap of a picture into an imageview, then using picasso, i'm resizing the images that are too big to directly uploaded to parse. I can resize the image in the image view using picasso but how do i get the bitmap from the image view to upload to parse? this is my code..

```
 public static final int IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST = 20;
    private ImageView imgPicture;
    public Bitmap image; 



 public void openGallery(View view){


    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // if we are here, everything processed successfully.
        if (requestCode == IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST) {

            Uri imageUri = data.getData();


            InputStream inputStream;


            try {
                inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);


                 image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);



                height= image.getHeight();
                h= String.valueOf(height);

                width= image.getWidth();
                w= String.valueOf(width);



               if (width>800 || height>600)
                {


                    Picasso.with(this)
                            .load(imageUri)
                            .resize(800,600)
                            .centerCrop()
                            .into(imgPicture);
                   // imgPicture.setImageBitmap(image);
                     //what should i write here to convert this imageview to bitmap? and then later use that bitmap to upload the image to parse?


                }
                else
                {
                    //do nothing
                    imgPicture.setImageBitmap(image);
                }


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // show a message to the user indictating that the image is unavailable.
                Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to open image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Huh? `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` returns a `Bitmap` not an `ImageView` - you already have what you need?

Comment: yes but i use that bitmap to find out the height and width of the picture. So that i know which pictures to resize. if i take that line out then i won't be able to do that..

Comment: i check the size of the picture and then use to find out which pictures are supposed to be resized. if the picture is bigger than 800x600 the picasso resizes it to 800x600 and puts that resized image into image view. now i want the bitmap of the image that is in the image view..

Answer (score 0):

You only can generate the bitmap from imageview but not in real image size, this generate the bitmap with imageview size

```
Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(YOUR_VIEW.getWidth(), YOUR_VIEW.getHeight(),
                        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                YOUR_VIEW.draw(canvas);

                File root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.PICTURES);

                String fname = "NAME_OF_FILE.jpg";
                file = new File(root, fname);

                try {
                    if (!root.exists()) {
                    root.mkdir();
                }
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    YOUR_VIEW.destroyDrawingCache();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
```

If you don't wanna save to a file, use this code:

```
public static Bitmap getScreenViewBitmap(View v) {
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    // this is the important code :)
    // Without it the view will have a dimension of 0,0 and the bitmap will be null
    v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());

    v.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache

    return b;
}
```